# Sorting and ranking a dataframe by date and time in r

Tags: r, date, time, rank

I have a dataframe as below.  Originally it was just two columns/variables -"Timestamp" (which contains date and time) and "Actor".  I broke down the "Timestamp" variable into "date" and "time" and then "time further down into "hours" and "mins".    This then gives the following structure

```
dataf<-structure(list(hours = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("9", 
"12", "14", "15", "16", "17"), class = "factor"), mins = structure(c(17L, 
1L, 2L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("00", "04", "08", 
"09", "10", "12", "13", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "27", "39", 
"51", "52", "59"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4/28/2014", "5/18/2014", "5/2/2014", 
"5/6/2014"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(7L, 8L, 9L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("12:18", "12:19", "12:27", 
"14:39", "14:51", "14:52", "14:59", "15:00", "15:04", "16:20", 
"16:21", "16:22", "17:08", "17:09", "17:12", "17:13", "9:04", 
"9:10"), class = "factor"), Timestamp = structure(c(13L, 14L, 
15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4/28/2014 12:18", "4/28/2014 12:19", 
"4/28/2014 12:27", "4/28/2014 9:04", "4/28/2014 9:10", "5/18/2014 17:08", 
"5/18/2014 17:09", "5/18/2014 17:12", "5/18/2014 17:13", "5/2/2014 14:39", 
"5/2/2014 14:51", "5/2/2014 14:52", "5/2/2014 14:59", "5/2/2014 15:00", 
"5/2/2014 15:04", "5/6/2014 16:20", "5/6/2014 16:21", "5/6/2014 16:22"
), class = "factor"), Actor = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 12L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("hours", 
"mins", "date", "time", "Timestamp", "Actor"), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = "data.frame")
```

The reason for breaking the timestamp and time variables down into separate variables was because in my real data I have had a lot of problems sorting by data and/or time.   Breaking these variables down into smaller chunks has made it much easier to sort.

What I would like to do now is create a new variable called "Rank", which would return a '1' for the earliest event in the dataframe (which would be the observation at 9.04am on the 28th April 2014), then a '2' for the next observation in date/time order and so on.

Sorting the dataframe appears to be relatively trivial:

```
dataf<-dataf[order(as.Date(dataf$date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), dataf$hours, dataf$mins),]
```

This does the job.  But what I am struggling with is now to assign ranks.

I tried this, because I have used 'ave' in combination with FUN=rank to rank integers, but what it produces is laughably wrong:

```
dataf$rank <- ave((dataf[order(as.Date(dataf$date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), dataf$hours, dataf$mins),]),FUN=rank )
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Isn't `dataf$rank <- rank(dataf$Timestamp)` enough?

Comment: @sgibb The OP has made life rather difficult by storing everything as factors, rather than using date and datetime objects, for some reason. And there are duplicate time stamps, so we can't even just side-step that issue and say to do `seq_len(nrow(dataf))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not share your aversion to datetime objects, which makes this all much simpler:

```
dataf$ts <- strptime(as.character(dataf$Timestamp),'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
dataf <- dataf[order(dataf$ts),]
dataf$ts_rank <- rank(dataf$ts,ties.method = "min")
dataf
##    hours mins      date  time       Timestamp Actor                  ts ts_rank
## 19     9   04 4/28/2014  9:04  4/28/2014 9:04     7 2014-04-28 09:04:00       1
## 20     9   10 4/28/2014  9:10  4/28/2014 9:10    10 2014-04-28 09:10:00       2
## 21    12   18 4/28/2014 12:18 4/28/2014 12:18     7 2014-04-28 12:18:00       3
## 22    12   18 4/28/2014 12:18 4/28/2014 12:18     7 2014-04-28 12:18:00       3
## 12    12   19 4/28/2014 12:19 4/28/2014 12:19     7 2014-04-28 12:19:00       5
## 13    12   19 4/28/2014 12:19 4/28/2014 12:19     7 2014-04-28 12:19:00       5
## 14    12   27 4/28/2014 12:27 4/28/2014 12:27     7 2014-04-28 12:27:00       7
## 15    12   27 4/28/2014 12:27 4/28/2014 12:27     7 2014-04-28 12:27:00       7
## 4     14   39  5/2/2014 14:39  5/2/2014 14:39     7 2014-05-02 14:39:00       9
## 5     14   51  5/2/2014 14:51  5/2/2014 14:51     7 2014-05-02 14:51:00      10
## 6     14   52  5/2/2014 14:52  5/2/2014 14:52     7 2014-05-02 14:52:00      11
## 1     14   59  5/2/2014 14:59  5/2/2014 14:59     7 2014-05-02 14:59:00      12
## 2     15   00  5/2/2014 15:00  5/2/2014 15:00     7 2014-05-02 15:00:00      13
## 3     15   04  5/2/2014 15:04  5/2/2014 15:04     7 2014-05-02 15:04:00      14
## 16    16   20  5/6/2014 16:20  5/6/2014 16:20    10 2014-05-06 16:20:00      15
## 17    16   21  5/6/2014 16:21  5/6/2014 16:21    10 2014-05-06 16:21:00      16
## 18    16   22  5/6/2014 16:22  5/6/2014 16:22    10 2014-05-06 16:22:00      17
## 7     17   08 5/18/2014 17:08 5/18/2014 17:08     5 2014-05-18 17:08:00      18
## 8     17   09 5/18/2014 17:09 5/18/2014 17:09     5 2014-05-18 17:09:00      19
## 9     17   12 5/18/2014 17:12 5/18/2014 17:12     2 2014-05-18 17:12:00      20
## 10    17   12 5/18/2014 17:12 5/18/2014 17:12    12 2014-05-18 17:12:00      20
## 11    17   13 5/18/2014 17:13 5/18/2014 17:13     2 2014-05-18 17:13:00      22
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I no longer possess an aversion to Timestamps.   To make sure that the ts_rank column has unique ranks (i.e. no rank can be shared, which is something my data needs) - I have gone with:     dataf$ts_rank <- rank(dataf$ts,ties.method = "random")